# How do I remove this door?

Tags: door-frame, hinges

As I don't know what these hinges are I can't google for the instructions.   It would make the painting easier if I could remove these doors, but I can't see how to remove the hinges.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a "TamBee Hidden Door Hinges Pivot Door Hinges Hinges for Secret Door L Shape" With part 1 and 2 installed the other way round.

[image]

Before finding these instructions, I turned the screw to far in the wrong direction so it is now lose somewhere inside. I order a replacements, the replacement have a better design that prevents the error I made.

I had to use a Bosch Professional 1x Expert MetalMax blade in my Multitool to cut the pin as my normal make of blade could not cope.

It turned out the hidges is not a TamBee but is the same dimensions.

Comment: In that case, I think the solution is to push the button by shoving something into the hole next to the screw in the upper door frame.  That's a guess but it seems to be what that lever arm mechanism is for.   Is that what you did?

Comment: I think the hole might contain a screw. I think you might need an allen key or a screwdriver. I suspect that turning it one way will raise the pin, and vice versa.

Comment: @jay613 It is a screw and I turned to far in the wrong direction so it is now lose somewhere inside.   A got a replacement on order, when it arrives I can see the design  in detail.   I expect I will need to cut the pin on the one I broke.

Comment: How awful.   If the screw mechanism became detached, maybe if you drill another hole as close to the door as possible, so it will be on the opposite side of the hinge, you could then insert something and push up on the lever to raise the pin.   And then you can remove and repair the top bracket.  Strange design!  I guess it's trying to be as flush and invisible as possible, you can trim the door very close to the top and bottom of the opening.

Answer (score 3):

Often the pins are different lengths, the top being longer than the bottom.

So, given  the gap at the top, try lifting the door up and take it off the lower pin then just tilt the door to free the top.

Comment: Tryed that, does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Possibly the pins retract into the door against a spring.  You need a thin tool and patience to achieve this.

Possibly there is a lever arm or latch holding the top or bottom of the door to the pin.  You swing this latch open with a screwdriver.

Possibly the hinge bracket is springy and can be pushed toward the floor or ceiling to release the pin.

Possibly the door can be lifted off the bottom hinge.

[ooh  ah] Possibly you shove something into the hole next to the screw in the upper door frame, to activate a mechanism that frees the upper hinge pin. (Based on the diagram posted in another answer).

With any of these the mechanism may be firmly stuck from rust, paint, debris, or damage.  Worst case saw off the hinge pin and replace it.

Comment: Typical closet bifold doors have a spring pin on the top.
Lift the door from the bottom and tilt away.
Install by inserting the pin in the top and lift into the bottom hole.

Comment: @DaveM,  That what I tried 1st, also the doors are full sized and fire door weight.   So seems to be a different system.

Comment: @DaveM  bifold doors have a track, this door does not.   Walker it might be difficult especially with a phone camera but can you take a clear picture of inside the gap at the top and bottom of the door?